# HTTP live stream of screen capture from VMs to iOS

Tags: ios, virtual-machine, vlc, http-live-streaming

I've set up an HTTP live stream of a screen capture of my computer and the necessary client-end code in iOS to watch the live stream, which I'm using to stream the "spectate" mode of the game League of Legends, which is running on my machine.

I'm wondering what would be involved in making this an app that other people could use to watch any game of League of Legends.  I have almost zero experience with servers as my background is in iOS, but would it be possible to start up a VM with League of Legends and VLC and the screen-capture software for each client requesting to spectate a different game?

I'm guessing I could set this up if I had a machine for each client requesting a stream, but I don't really know whether or how I can run many VMs on a server and what that would cost me.

Answer (score 0):

check out something like justin.tv (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QP4HfCOfeUQ)
There are a number of other application virtualization technoliges as well. check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_App-V and the list at the bottom of similar products.